# Archive limit the text of the_content

Tags: pages, archives, excerpt, text

here's the code for my archive page..

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archive Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id ="maincontent"class = "group">
        <?php include'leftsidebar.php';?>
    <div id = "allcontent"class="archive">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>

        <?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>
            <h2>Archive for the &#8216;<?php single_cat_title(); ?>&#8217; Category</h2>

        <?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
            <h2>Posts Tagged &#8216;<?php single_tag_title(); ?>&#8217;</h2>

        <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
            <h2>Archive for <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h2>

        <?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
            <h2>Archive for <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?></h2>

        <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
            <h2>Archive for <?php the_time('Y'); ?></h2>

        <?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
            <h2>Author Archive</h2>

        <?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
            <h2>Blog Archives</h2>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' );?>

        <ul>
        <?php $i=0;?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php $i++; ?>
            <li class ="group">
            <div <?php post_class() ?>>

                <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

                <div class="entry">

                    <?php the_content();?>
                </div>

            </div>
            </li>
            <?php 
            $Archive_Ads = array(
            'Archive Ad1',
            'Archive Ad2',
            'Archive Ad3'
            );
            if ($i % 3 === 0):
            if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) :/*this is the line 69*/
            dynamic_sidebar($Archive_Ads[rand(0, 2)]);
            endif;
            endif;
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>



        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2>Nothing found</h2>

<?php endif; ?>


    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now What I want is to limit the text by 50 words without affecting the videos and images, I want my Images and Videos to be display, is it possible to do that?

Comment: So when you're on the Archive page, you just want to display the first 50 words?

Comment: yup, that's what I wanted., I forgot to say.. the images and videos are just inserted in the post, I'm not using the featured Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming 'Archive Page' is a custom template and not either of the WP archive pages (category/date/author/tag/taxonomy). Try using this:

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content', 'trim_content');

function trim_content($content)
{
    if(is_archive())
    {
        //use your own trick to get the first 50 words. I'm getting the first 100 characters just to show an example.
        $content = (strlen($content) <= 100)? $content : wp_html_excerpt($content, 100);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

I think this will do the job.

Comment: It's now working for me, I added the funtion in my functions.php and relplace my <?php the_content();?> with <?php trim_content($content);?> in my archive.

is there somthing wrong from what I've did? sorry, I'm not good in PHP..

Comment: You just need to add this in `functions.php`, WP will take care of the function call! Leave `the_content()` as it is. Also, have you put the filename with the extension properly?

Comment: `add_filter('the_content', 'trim_content');

function trim_content($content)
{
    if(is_page_template('archive.php'))
    {
        //use your own trick to get the first 50 words. I'm getting the first 100 characters just to show an example.
        $content = (strlen($content) <= 50)? $content : wp_html_excerpt($content, 50);
    }

    return $content;
}`

tha'ts the code that I added to my functions.php, and nothings happen.

Comment: Ohh! It means you're using WPs archives. I'm changing my code in the answer. Please check.

Comment: How can I give you a reputation?, sorry I didn't know.

Comment: First tell me, did the solution work?

Comment: No, it's now working, i'm just asking so that I can give you a reputation point, no matter what happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot man but don't give me any points if the solution doesn't work! We cannot chat as you don't have the score or I would've helped you out in chat. Btw, did you copy paste my code in the `functions.php` file, and then check, without changing `the_content()`?

Comment: I really don't know what what the problem is, but it's not working.. I didn't change any single code in my archive.php.. I just copy and paste your whole code in functions.php.. and nothings happen,

Comment: here's the page that using archive.php 
http://pinoytopics.com/livelong/2011/10/

Comment: I checked my code locally, and it worked fine! Did you, by mistake, copy the code with `<?php` tag? It could be one reason for the code not working.

Comment: here's the screenshot of how I pasted your code in my functions.php http://i42.tinypic.com/dwx4ba.jpg

Comment: The code seems fine, but there's another function hooked to `the_content`, which may be causing the problem. I'm modifying your template for an alternate solution. Comment out my code from your `functions.php` and check this: http://pastebin.com/3fkx1zmP

Comment: It doesn't work again.. take a look at the output 
http://i39.tinypic.com/2wfpbgi.jpg

I want share to you my funtions.php if some of the funtions are affecting your code.
http://pastebin.com/071RrzJf

Comment: Ohh, sorry, my bad... change `get_the_permalink()` to `get_permalink()`.

Comment: @rarst Apologies, I tried to move to chat, but markyeoj has only 1 reputation, so couldn't!

Comment: hello rutwick.. nice to get back herem I still  don't have any solution in my problem, did you delete your code in pastebin because I can't see it now.

Comment: it's now working.. thanks... :) I would like to give you a reputation point, how can I?

Comment: That is such a good news! I deserve the reputation now! Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: how can I mark this as resolved?